# Using gensim python from Java with jython

Tags: java, python, jython, gensim

I want to use the gensim library in a python code and need to execute that code from Java.

Following is the python code, sent2vec.py:

```
import gensim
sentences = gensim.models.doc2vec.LabeledLineSentence('/tmp/sentence.tmp')
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(sentences, size=10, window=5, min_count=2, workers=4)
model.save_word2vec_format('/tmp/sentenceVectors.txt')
```

The code is running fine in a standalone mode, i.e. when executed by:

```
python sent2vec.py
```

But I need to call this function from a java code. I tried using Jython but having errors. My java code looks like the following:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); //output will be stored here
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();

context.setWriter(writer); //configures output redirection
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
engine.eval(new FileReader("sent2vec.py"), context);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

I am having this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named gensim in <script> at line number 1
at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.scriptException(PyScriptEngine.java:202)
at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:42)
at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:47)
Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<script>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gensim

at org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Py.java:328)
at org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:877)
at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:972)
at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:1062)
at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1280)
at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:431)
at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1232)
at org.python.core.imp.importOne(imp.java:1081)
at org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(<script>:5)
at org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(<script>)
at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1386)
at org.python.core.__builtin__.eval(__builtin__.java:497)
at org.python.core.__builtin__.eval(__builtin__.java:501)
at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.eval(PythonInterpreter.java:259)
at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:40)
... 3 more
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with importing gensim:
    engine.eval("import gensim");
is rising the same kind of error.

Comment: Same is happening when trying to import nltk.
Importing any module which are not bundled with python is having problem. Please help.